# Unable to get dataLocationCode value from SiteCollection

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I am trying to get the `DataLocationCode` value of any site.

I have tried various syntaxes on Graph Explorer(see below). I am new to building my own query strings, I normally use simple calls via the C# SDK instead. Whilst I do need to obtain this `DataLocationCode` so that I can use the `Search` endpoint, I am also using this problem as an excuse to better understand OData query string for Ms Graph.

**Simple call**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}
```

returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites/$entity",
    "@microsoft.graph.tips": "Use $select to choose only the properties your app needs, as this can lead to performance improvements. For example: GET sites('<key>')?$select=displayName,error",
    "createdDateTime": "2023-08-10T15:14:45.583Z",
    "description": "a_description",
    "id": "tenant.sharepoint.com,some_guid,some_guid",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2023-08-20T12:10:08Z",
    "name": "P008-Baltik",
    "webUrl": "https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/some_name",
    "displayName": "some site name",
    "root": {},
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "tenantname.sharepoint.com"
    }
}
```

**$select call**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}?$select=siteCollection
```

returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites(siteCollection)/$entity",
    "siteCollection": {
        "hostname": "tenant.sharepoint.com"
    }
}
```

**Nested $select call (tentative)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}?$select=siteCollection/dataLocationCode
```

returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Select options are not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-28T14:58:15",
            "request-id": "some_guid",
            "client-request-id": "some_guid"
        }
    }
}
```

**$expand call**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteid}?$expand=siteCollection&select=dataLocationCode
```

returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Property 'siteCollection' on type 'microsoft.graph.site' is not a navigation property or complex property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-28T15:18:10",
            "request-id": "some_guid",
            "client-request-id": "some_guid"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `/Search` endpoint with a random `region` code (for example `US` or `ABC`). The endpoint will return an OData error which includes the possible region codes, for example:

> Requested region not found. Only valid regions are EMEA.

The table with all possible codes is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide

Note this table does not include `EMEA`, which is a valid code in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite often experiencing the same issue that the endpoint `/sites` doesn't return the `dataLocationCode`.

I would recommend to try another endpoint `/sites/getAllSites` which returns [sites across geographies in an organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-getallsites?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). But this endpoint supports only application permissions, so it won't work in the Graph Explorer.

Anyway, if you need the `dataLocationCode` for `/search` endpoint, the default value is `US`.

Check the table below with all possible values for `dataLocationCode`.

| Code | Geo location |
| --- | --- |
| US | United States |
| APC | Macro Region Geography 2 - Asia-Pacific |
| AUS | Australia |
| BRA | Brazil |
| CAN | Canada |
| EUR | Macro Region Geography 1 - EMEA |
| FRA | France |
| DEU | Germany |
| IND | India |
| JPN | Japan |
| KOR | Korea |
| NAM | Macro Region Geography 3 - Americas |
| NOR | Norway |
| QAT | Qatar |
| POL | Poland |
| ZAF | South Africa |
| SWE | Sweden |
| CHE | Switzerland |
| ARE | United Arab Emirates |
| GBR | United Kingdom |

Comment: `/sites/getAllSites` does not give me the `dataLocationCode` either. However, I did try the search with US and got the following error message, which allowed me to find the correct location: `Requested region not found. Only valid regions are EMEA.`

Comment: @Ama In that case try the code EUR

Comment: The `EMEA` code works. Where did you get the table you show in your reponse?

Comment: @Ama Recently found the table here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/microsoft-365-multi-geo?view=o365-worldwide No info in the Graph Doc.

Comment: Thanks! Strange that EMEA is not in the list but does work...